# I am unable to click the close icon in panel window using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to close the panel window using selenium webdriver. But I can't handle this. When I click on close button, I got an exception as "Unable to locate Element".

HTML code:-

```
<a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button" href="#"> <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span>
```

Here is the code:

```
    WebElement containerEle = driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe"));
    driver.switchTo().frame(containerEle);
    //driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.ui-icon.ui-icon-closethick")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='ext-gen4']/div[4]/div[1]/a/span")).click();
```

And find the attachment for your reference.
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post your HTML code so we can help you better ... check if there is any frame present

Comment: Please provide page source HTML..

Comment: <a class="ui-dialog-titlebar-close ui-corner-all" role="button" href="#">
 <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick">close</span> @ShubhamJain

Answer (score 0):

Try click using `JavascriptExecutor` :-

```
JavascriptExecutor executor = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
executor.executeScript("arguments[0].click();", element);
```

`element` is the WebElement on which you want to click

Answer (score 0):

I would try to click on the `<a>` tag instead:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(driver.findElement(By.tagName("iframe")));
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close")).click();
```